# .net MVC - one-item List not passing to controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, parameters

I'm working on a bit of legacy code that uses MVC version 2.2.5. The change involves taking an existing decimal property and making it a List instead.

It's declared in the ViewModel class like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:f2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public List<decimal> AnnualCharge { get; set; } = new List<decimal>();
```

And in the first controller action where it's used in a controller, it's populated like this:

```
model.AnnualCharge.Add(1.1m);
```

In the controller, I've changed it to display by iterating through the list:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Values.AnnualCharge.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AnnualCharge[i], "{0:f2}", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "form-control number-value" }, { "type", "number" }, { "min", 0 }, { "step", 0.01 }, { "max-percent", Model.MaxCharge } })
}
```

And this displays as expected in the View. However, when it posts back to a controller action that receives this ViewModel as a parameter, the array is empty.

This seems to be connected to the fact I'm passing a List rather than any other failure in the typing. If I add a second value to the list:

```
model.AnnualCharge.Add(1.1m);
model.AnnualCharge.Add(1.2m);
```

It works absolutely fine. Whether I type an actual decimal or an integer into the box or whether I declare the new List(); in the ViewModel or in the controller seems irrelevant. If I pass a single value back, it's not received in the postback. If I pass two values back, they come through as expected.

How can I ensure that a single-item list is received at the post method?